# PHP cURL and file_get_contents give different results?

Tags: php

I'm trying to code an RSS scraper that will pull down a feed and use XMLReader (or DOMdocument) to spit out a list of available tags.

My host does not enable file_get_contents so I pull the feed down into a variable and then use the "load from string" way of instantiating my XMLreader or DOMdocument (I've tried both methods so far).

When I test on my local box (where I enable file_get_contents) my script is able to pull out the XML tags.  When I use cURL, however, I get a range of errors.

I have already tried to UTF8 encode the string after using html_entity_decode.

The cURL options I am using are:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If I grab the text from the feed with my browser and save it as a file on my box then my script is also able to recognize the tags.

The error I am getting when using cURL is a parsing error.

So my question is - what settings must I use with cURL to be able to parse RSS?

Comment: file_get_contents likely ignores or transparently works around HTTP. cURL does not. Therefore, the best way to solve the problem is likely through testing the differences between file_get_contents and cURL. What have you tried already?

Comment: if hosts disables basic php functions -move host.

Comment: Trying random  functions for post-processing ain't helpful. You need to know why there was a parser error. Since you didn't tell us about that parser error, you probably want to solve it yourself. -- The reason cURL and fopen may return different results is due to different request headers. In particular `Accept:` and `Accept-Encoding:` might be relevant. -- Also, there are existing RSS parsers for PHP. Why not use one?

Comment: Thanks Mario and Josh - the headers comment was useful.  I will probably consider using an external class to parse my RSS.  

Pranav - I get hundreds of errors, relating to unclosed or mismatched tags.  The parse errors look like HTML is confusing the parser.  But the XML parses just fine with file_get_contents or if I read from disk - so the feed is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use file_get_contents() for a remote file, it is very slow, very cpu intensive, and does not handle redirects, caching, cookies, etc. like the flexibility you have with curl.

Even better than curl; faster, more flexible, and less cpu intensive is using fsocket... there are many php classes that make it dead simple to do this, here is one of my favorites:

http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/